# Docker pull fails after continuous retrying to download

Tags: docker, pull

```html
$ docker pull oraclelinux
Using default tag: latest
latest: Pulling from library/oraclelinux
c93adbd5ca8c: Downloading [==================================================>]  85.96MB/85.96MB
unexpected EOF

$ docker --version
Docker version 18.09.2, build 6247962
```

I notice that docker pull continously retries with back-off for a few times and eventually fails with unexpected EOF. Same issue observed if pulling centos, debian image.

The docker pull of this image from a repository in local network succeeds. I'm trying to figure out the failure for pulls from github.io.

docker pull for smaller size images (ex: alpine, helloworld) succeeds.

Running Docker Desktop Version 2.0.0.3 (31259) on MacOS High Sierra. Restarting Docker did not resolve the issue.

Any pointers are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer. I had to use Manual Proxy Configuration within Docker Desktop to point to an internal corp proxy for this to work.